# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table when using foreign keys

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

what is wrong with the two foreign keys which I have marked with comments?

```sql
create database db;
use db;

create table Flug(
  Flugbez varchar(20),
  FDatum Date,
  Ziel varchar(20),
  Flugzeit int,
  Entfernung int,
  Primary Key (Flugbez, FDatum)
);

create table Flugzeugtyp(
  Typ varchar(20),
  Hersteller varchar(20),
  SitzAnzahl int,
  Reisegeschw int,
  primary key (Typ)
);

create table flugzeug(
  Typ varchar(20),
  SerienNr int,
  AnschDatum Date,
  FlugStd int,
  primary key(Typ,SerienNr),
  foreign key(Typ) references Flugzeugtyp(Typ)
);

create table Abflug(
  Flugbez varchar(20),
  FDatum Date,
  Typ varchar(20),
  Seriennr int,
  Kaptaen varchar(20),
  Primary key(Flugbez,FDatum,Typ,SerienNr),
  Foreign key(Flugbez) references Flug(Flugbez),
  -- Foreign key(FDatum) references Flug(FDatum),
  Foreign key(Typ) references Flugzeugtyp(Typ)
  -- ,Foreign key(SerienNr) references Flugzeug(SerienNr)
);
```

When I uncomment the foreign keys, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'db.abflug' (errno: 150)
```

I use a Standard Installation of MySQL Server 5.5.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the primary keys you're referencing are compound keys, but you're only trying to reference one of the columns (not the first) in the foreign keys.

For instance, you define the primary key `primary key(Typ,SerienNr)` in table flugzeug but in table Abflug you try to reference `Foreign key(SerienNr) references Flugzeug(SerienNr)`.

You must reference the whole key (`Foreign key(Typ, SerienNr) references Flugzeug(Typ,SerienNr)`).

Answer (score 0):

When executing your SQL code, the full message I get is:

```
[HY000][1822] Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'abflug_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'flug'
```

This means, that your column `Flug.Flugbez` is not indexed in `Flug`. You only created an index for the primary key which is a combination of `Flugbez` and `FDatum`. To achieve what you need, you have to create an index for `Flug.Flugbez` or reference the primary key `Flugbez, FDatum`.

Same applies for `Flug.FDatum` and `Flugzeug.SerienNr` that are referenced with `Abflug.FDatum`, `Abflug.SerienNr`.

**To solve your issue you can create indexes for each column you are referencing.** Example index creation you may adjust a little:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_flugbez ON Flug (Flugbez);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_flugdatum ON Flug (FDatum);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_seriennr ON flugzeug (SerienNr);
```